# Convert hundred of numbers in a column to row separated by a comma

Tags: text-processing

How can I convert the following from a column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
.
.
.
.
98
99
100
```

To a row separated by a comma:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,....,98,99,100
```

I am using Linux.

Comment: You mention "a column", not "rows".  Does that mean that you are working with multiple columns and trying to transpose a larger data set, column by column?

Answer (score 19):

You may use the `paste` command as follows:

```bash
paste -sd, file.txt
```

By default, `paste` "write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each file, separated by tabs, to standard output" (quoted from manual). The `-d`option sets an alternative output delimiter and the `-s` option makes it paste file one at a time instead of in parallel. In the case of a singular file, this option makes it process the file one line at a time.

Comment: @golf4life That should work as stated, assuming your input data is actually a Unix text file and not a DOS or Windows text file. If it is from a Windows system, convert it to a Unix text file with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Also, @golf4life please make sure that your example accurately represents your data. If you have IPs, then you also have `.` not just numbers and that can affect the tools we use. Please ensure that the example you give is as close to your real data as possible.

Comment: @golf4life whether the input is numbers or IP addresses or names of fish or anything else is irrelevant to this solution. "That didn't really work" is the worst possible problem statement as it doesn't tell us anything about the failure that we could use to help you debug the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Here are a few ways (although [Loïc's `paste` approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754370/22222) is probably the best):

- `tr`

  ```
  $ tr '\n' , < file
  1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100,$
  ```

  This will replace all newline characters with a comma, but that means that the final, trailing newline will also be changed, so you want to add that one back (note that this assumes GNU `sed`, but that's what you have on a Linux machine usually):

  ```
  $ tr '\n' , < file | sed 's/,$/\n/'
  1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
  ```
- Perl & `sed`

  ```
  $ perl -pe 's/\n/,/' file | sed 's/,$/\n/'
  1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
  ```
- Perl alone

  ```
  $ perl -lne 'push @l,$_; END{print join ",",@l; }' file 
  1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  $ perl -0777 -pe 's/\n/,/g; s/,$/\n/;' file 
  1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
  ```

  The `-0777` tells perl to "slurp" the file, reading the whole thing into memory. Then, we replace all newlines with commas, and replace the final comma with a newline. The `-pe` means "**p**rint every line of the input file after applying the script given by `-e`".

  Note that both of these approach store the entire file in memory, so they might not be appropriate for very large files.
- `awk` & `sed`

  ```
  $ awk -v ORS="," '1' file | sed 's/,$/\n/'
  1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
  ```
- Pure `awk` (with thanks to [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) who provided this approach in a comment)

  ```
  $ awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}' file 
  1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
  ```

  The `1` is just a shorthand for "print". In awk, the default action when something evaluates to true is to print the current line, so `1` is often used since `1` is always true.

Comment: should be able to do slightly shorter in Perl with `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?!\z)/,/g;'`, using a negative lookahead to avoid replacing the newline at the end

Comment: A POSIX compliant way to handle the trailing comma with any `sed` would be `sed 's/,$//;G'`. Btw, I'm missing the `sed`-only solution `sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n/,/g'`

Comment: @Philippos it's missing because I've never learned sed well enough for things like that, I'll just use peel instead. Please post it as an answer or edit it into one of the existing ones, it's a good solution!

Answer (score 12):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```bash
$ datamash -t , transpose <file
1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
```

This would also correctly transpose your data if it was made up of *multiple* comma-delimited columns (i.e., if it was a *simple* CSV format):

```bash
$ cat f
1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6
.,.,.,.
.,.,.,.
.,.,.,.
.,.,.,.
98,98,98,98
99,99,99,99
100,100,100,100
```

```bash
$ datamash -t , transpose <f
1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
1,2,3,4,5,6,.,.,.,.,98,99,100
```

Comment: If all rows have one column only then `datamash collapse 1` would give same output.

Answer (score 7):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl6)

```
~$ raku -e 'lines.join(",").put;'  file
```

Raku has a workhorse `lines` routine, which strips off line terminators by default, returning a `Seq`, which is a lightweight iterable data structure in Raku. If you need a comma-separated row simply `join` on commas (otherwise you'll get output with elements separated by a single space).

Sample Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Sample Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

In Raku, `put` and `say` will add the newline terminator back for you (although `say` should be withheld from production scripts, it is only for code review as it returns "human-readable" output). Raku also has `print`, which does not add a newline at the end.

The default in Raku is basically equivalent to Perl's `-l` command-line flag, where newlines are auto-chomped upon input. Thus by using `print` for output you can come up with simple code in the same vein as the "Perl & `sed`" answer by @terdon (note below `~` tilde is used for string concatenation, but you could just as easily write `print "$_,"` instead):

```
~$ raku -ne 'print $_ ~ ",";' file.txt | raku -pe  's/\,$//;'
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed` solution for completeness' sake:

```bash
% cat =commas
#!/bin/bash

# Other ways of doing it:
#sed -n 'H;${g;s/\n//;s//,/g;p}'
#sed -n '1h;1!H;${g;s/\n/,/g;p}'

sed ':b;N;$!bb;s/\n/,/g'
```

I think I'm going to start using Loïc's `paste` solution though.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated for a `sed` solution, you could just use `sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$//' file`

Comment: @sseLtaH Except, your command modifies the contents of the lines. `printf 'foo,\0bar\nbaz\n' | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$//'` turns to `foo\0bar,baz`, which isn't even newline terminated. You can make assumptions that the data won't have this or won't have that, but I rather consider lines to be newline-terminated bytes of anything, and the output of line-oriented pipelines should be newline-terminated as well unless there's good reason it needs to lack the newline.

Answer (score 2):

A bash solution would the two-liner

```bash
mapfile -t nums < file
( IFS=,; echo "${nums[*]}" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution (using Perl) that avoids reading the whole input file into memory at once:

```bash
perl -pe 'print "," if $. > 1; chomp unless eof'
```

The `-p` switch makes Perl wrap the program code (given directly afterwards as an argument to the `-e` switch) in a loop that reads lines from standard input (or from the files given as further command line arguments, if any) into the "default input variable" `$_` and print them out after the code has executed, then repeat.

The `print "," if $. > 1` command prints a comma (which will appear *before* the automatically printed output line) `if` (and only if) the number of lines read so far (`$.`) is greater than one.  Meanwhile, `chomp unless eof` removes the trailing newline (if any) from the input line before it's printed unless the end of the input (`eof`) has been reached.  Thus, together, these two commands add a comma before all input lines except the first one and remove the trailing line break from all but the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Paste is, to me, the best suited for your exemple (and datamash if you really need to "transpose" a file that could have multiple columns).

However here is another way, if you have not many elements:

```
xargs <file | tr ' ' ','
 # xargs will output all elements on the same line, separated with a space,
 # and tr will then changes those separators into ","
# a big caveat of the xargs approach (often forgotten...) : 
# if you have a lot (thousands?) of elements:
#   xargs will maybe output several lines, and this will not work properly.
#   (xargs: tries to fit the elements on the same line until it reaches the length of a 
#    command line, and will outputs on another line to continue fitting the next elements)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `tr` command. Convert all newline characters to commas as follows (Input is shown at the end):

```
$ cat ab.txt | tr '\n' ','
```

However, this may consider the '\n' in the end and print it this way:

```
┌──(user㉿user)-[~/Desktop/abc]
└─$ cat ab.txt | tr '\n' ','
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
```

To remove the last comma, cut the output to 11 fields (columns):

```
┌──(user㉿user)-[~/Desktop/abc]
└─$ cat ab.txt | tr '\n' ',' | cut -d "," -f1-11
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Note: -d stands for delimiter here. It means that the columns of data given as input to the `cut` statement are separated by commas.

`ab.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Comment: `tr` was already covered in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754372/70524

Comment: @muru You are right. It has been covered by terdon in the same question, I had not noticed it before. Thanks for pointing that out!